# New Zealand or Canada, which is the better destination?

Tags: canada, resident-permit, indian-citizens, new-zealand

From career aspect, I am a front-end web developer, received *Permanent Residence* status for both New Zealand and Saskatchewan (Canada). Currently a citizen of India.

I cannot move out of Saskatchewan province, for next 3 years, as per the PR norms.

New Zealand has better climate.
Canada is a better place for IT jobs.

But, in the long term, which one is the better place to live as a family man?

Comment: That's wonderful news! The largest cities in Saskatchewan are only 200k each, so pretty small. Have you found many job possibilities already?

Comment: @mkennedy No, am yet to try for a job in either NZ or CANADA? Am yet to go for VISA stamping. It will take 3-4 months from now, until I move. Am confused, on how to decide the destination? Which place do you belong to? I clearly know that, it is easy for me to get a job in Auckland(NZ). Am to do research on Saskatchewan IT market. But entering CANADA is more worthy for long term, because our communities can be found easily.

Comment: I'm in the US, so I would be going on just general information. You might want to start checking the job sites for Regina and Saskatoon (newspaper want ads, monster.com, stack overflow careers) and for the various cities in NZ that look interesting.

Comment: @mkennedy I could not find a single job relevant to my background in Saskatoon and Regina. Unlike in Auckland/Wellington I find lot of relevant jobs.

Comment: I just found out a colleague is from Regina. Given a choice, he recommended Saskatoon. There's more crime in Regina, but it's mainly theft, fights. Currently, the economy seems okay there, and still growing a bit compared to Canada overall. Oil&gas-related jobs are down now. He also said this winter is predicted to be the mildest in quite a while.

Comment: @mkennedy Is your colleague working in IT sector? Can he share in-person knowledge of IT sector in saskatoon?

Comment: Probably not; we're in a specialized field (GIS) and he's been in the US for a number of years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [Employment by major industry group, seasonally adjusted, by province](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/tables-tableaux/sum-som/l01/cst01/labr67i-eng.htm). The main industries I know so far over there are agriculture and fishing. Since you are in IT, if you were to go in SK, the chances of getting a job in your field might be less.

Also the winters are *brutal* in SK. I have some friends over there but they are not in IT so they wouldn't know about the industry over there. (PS I am in Toronto). I have seen very early snowfall over there. And the weather is unpredictable (That stands for most of Canada by the way).

I don't know much about New Zealand, but I could find [this](https://www.newzealandnow.govt.nz/work-in-nz/nz-jobs-industries) about the employment diversities over there. Engineering is the **fourth ranked industry** over there. Also Auckland has some promising companies on their [employment page](http://www.workhere.co.nz/region/auckland/work-here).

For career, I would say SK is not the best option. I would recommend you to move to some other province like Ontario, Alberta, Quebec or British Columbia; but since you can't move outside for three years, that goes out of the picture.

For a family, the winters are going to be hard. You and your family will struggle adjusting to the weather here. Again this is from my personal experience.

Also there is not much difference between [NZD](https://www.google.ca/search?q=nzd+inr) and [CAD](https://www.google.ca/search?q=cad+inr) if you're thinking about the finances too. So if you hopefully find a job in Auckland or any other major cities, you're off to having better chances over there than Canada.

Comment: Am very clear that I can easily get my relevant job in NZ. But my family would like to be in touch with indian society/festival. Unlike Canada, NZ has such problem. Job in SK is risky.

Comment: SK again has less Indian population compared to Ontario, Alberta, British Columbia or Winnipeg in that matter. If you're ready to give up your first three years and then move somewhere else then that's an option. For IT I would say Ontario or British Columbia are better. Quebec is good too but you should know French in Quebec.

Comment: How many exact days in first 3 years, do I need to stay in Saskatchewan to gain citizenship in CANADA? In NZ, I need to stay 184 days for first two years to get citizenship.

Comment: Seems like you have a plan now. Good luck.

Comment: When you say, *since you can't move outside for three years*, Are you saying that, I need to stick to SK province for 3 years?

Comment: That's what you said your limitations are right? I believe you have a provincial residence?

Comment: I get a PR card, which does not mention any province name. Am still not sure, if I need to stay for 3 years.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You said in your question I can't move out of SK for 3 years as per PR norms. Could you clarify if you can move out of SK Anytime you want or not?

Comment: As per charter rights, if one obtains PR card, then, he can move to other province.so my statement is wrong

Comment: Then you should choose another province. Consider Ontario or British Columbia. Lots of Indian and IT Jobs over these places.

Comment: Now the question is, as I can move to Ontario or BC, can I avoid NZ trip, completely?

Comment: Sure you can. What's stopping you

Comment: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RBcXClTzJYY  this link clearly confirms that I can move out

Comment: I'm not sure how the rules of provincial permanent residence work here but I am fairly sure that some kind of provincial residences impose restrictions to you for not moving out of the particular province. Not sure if you fall in the category or not

Comment: Did you have a provincial nomination?

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to address some of your specific points:

> New Zealand has better climate. Canada is a better place for IT jobs.

Canada is a really big place. While Canada as a whole you might consider "better" for IT jobs, if you are restricted to Saskatchewan then you will find your options greatly limited. On the other hand, Auckland has a thriving software development community, and you could move anywhere in New Zealand if you wanted to.

> But my family would like to be in touch with indian society/festival. Unlike Canada, NZ has such problem.

Auckland is a multicultural city and has a wide range of cultural influences from India. As an example, the recent [Auckland Diwali Festival](http://www.aucklandnz.com/diwali) attracted [thousands of people](https://www.3news.co.nz/nznews/thousands-flock-to-aucklands-diwali-festival-2015101709):

> "It's a demonstration of our diverse and accepting culture that it is also a festival that many other New Zealanders of all ethnic groups eagerly await," Mr Lotu-Iiga [Minister for Ethnic Communities] says.

If connection with Indian culture is important to you and your family, and it sounds like it is, I would strongly suggest considering your options in Auckland (largest city in the country, ~1.3 million people), versus your choice of much smaller city in Saskatchewan (max. ~200k people).

Google tells me that the [Indian population within Auckland](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=indian%20population%20auckland) is roughly 146,500 people. The [South Asian population within the entire province of Saskatchewan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Saskatchewan) is only 5,130. (Keep in mind that when you're looking up things like this, the term "Indian" in Canada has historically been used to refer to the [indigenous peoples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboriginal_peoples_in_Canada), but the terms "aboriginal" or "First Nations" are preferred for those people today. People from the country of India are often referred to as "East Indian" or "South Asian".)

Coming from a country with essentially no snow and warm climate (India), the Saskatoon winters are going to be *shocking*. From about November through March, the average daily maximum temperature is below freezing (below 0° C). Snow can fall anytime from October through about May, sometimes quite a lot (see [news story from April 2015](http://globalnews.ca/news/1962200/spring-snow-storm-hits-central-saskatchewan/)). Driving will be difficult or impossible on some winter days.

Comment: One correction in my query isthat, I can move from Saskatchewan province to other province, after gaining PR card. Sorry for this correction. I clearly understand the climatic advantage in NZ. CANADA has old age pension benefits.

Comment: Well, that totally changes the nature of your question, doesn't it?

Comment: Shall I edit the question, that single line? Please read this [comment](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7221/new-zealand-or-canada-which-is-the-better-destination/7239#comment9574_7224)

Comment: No. Changing the question would make *both* answers appear irrelevant. If you have a more general question about New Zealand compared to Canada, ask a new question. This question is about New Zealand compared to Saskatchewan.

Comment: In the circumstance of moving out of SK province in first 3-4 months, How would you see the situation? Is CANADA better for me?CANADA also has pension benefits

Comment: New Zealand has [New Zealand Superannuation](http://www.workandincome.govt.nz/individuals/a-z-benefits/nz-superannuation.html), same sort of thing by another name. Looks like it can be considerably more money than what Canada offers (but you'd have to work it out for your own circumstances).

Comment: Cost of living is lot lesser in SK compared to NZ. Monthly rent is $600 per month in SK.NZ has 300 Nzd per week.

Comment: Well, if you've already made your decision, then I won't waste any further amount of your time.

Comment: No I havent made any decision. How would it be, to stay 6 months in Auckland and decide, what to do? before moving to SK? To be honest, CANADA being a dream destination(mindset) is killing my rationale to choose a better place.

Comment: If your dream is to live in Canada, and you now have the opportunity, then follow your dream! Canada is great. I was just trying to give you more information to help make your decision. I'm a citizen of both Canada and NZ, and I live in NZ, so I might be slightly biased.

Comment: Are you basically from CANADA?

Comment: I was born in Canada. I consider New Zealand home now.

Comment: Do you work in  IT sector?

Comment: What made you leave Canada and settle in NZ? Would you like to share? This may help me

Comment: Well, it's a long story, directly related to me and my circumstances, that wouldn't necessarily be useful for anybody else's decision making. I left Canada many years before moving to NZ, so it wasn't simply a choice between the two countries.